# nest_by on R and running multiple models

Tags: r

I am fairly new to this community and R, thank you for all the support. 
I encountered the new nest_by option of dplyr and it seems rather good. I have managed to split existing Dataframe and but not to run multiple models with them. I would like to iterate through all the dataframes and get raw and summary data of statistical models (GLM models mainly).

```
library(tidyverse)

nested <- mtcars %>% nest_by (cyl,carb)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Rowwise:  cyl, carb
    cyl  carb               data
  <dbl> <dbl> <list<tbl_df[,9]>>
1     4     1            [5 x 9]
2     4     2            [6 x 9]
3     6     1            [2 x 9]
4     6     4            [4 x 9]
5     6     6            [1 x 9]
6     8     2            [4 x 9]
7     8     3            [3 x 9]
8     8     4            [6 x 9]
9     8     8            [1 x 9]

#Now i would like to run each line seperately in a lm model. This line should do it, but it doesn't

fit<- nested %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(mpg~hp, data=.)))


Now, I am trying to make a printable version of all models for my statistics teacher. 

nested <- mtcars %>% nest (data = -c(cyl,carb))

regressions <-nested %>% 
  mutate(
    fit = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ hp, data = .x))
  )

printing<- regressions %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate (printed =  paste(carb, cyl, "This model summary is"), summary(fit),  sep  = '*') 

However this doesn't work altogether.

Any thoughts?
```

Comment: I am not sure about your exact question. Have you had a chance to look at the new tidymodels website? https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/

Comment: This video shows how to fit 1 model on multiple dataframes and also how to fit multiple models on 1 dataframe: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOfK3sBsCuA

Comment: Thanks, I have used some of the resources and modified the last line, still no luck..

Comment: Please show what you changed and the error. Also, please explain in detail what exactly is it that you want to achieve/expected output. That helps in debugging.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: In your precise case try this:

```r
nested <- mtcars %>% nest (data = -c(cyl,carb))


regressions <-nested %>% 
  mutate(
    fit = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ hp, data = .x)),
    tidied = map(fit, tidy),
    glanced = map(fit, glance),
    augmented = map(fit, augment)
  )

regressions %>% 
  unnest(glanced) # to get statistics of fits

regressions %>% 
  unnest(tidied) # to get coefficients of all fits
```

You can use `dplyr` in combination with `broom` as in this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html). There is an exact example with `mtcars`:

```r
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- as_tibble(mtcars)  # to play nicely with list-cols
mtcars
## # A tibble: 32 x 11
##      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
##    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
##  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
##  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
##  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
##  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
##  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
##  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
##  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
##  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
##  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
## 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
## # ... with 22 more rows
mtcars %>%
  nest(-am) %>% 
  mutate(
    fit = map(data, ~ lm(wt ~ mpg + qsec + gear, data = .x)),  # S3 list-col
    tidied = map(fit, tidy)
  ) %>% 
  unnest(tidied)
## # A tibble: 8 x 8
##      am data              fit    term       estimate std.error statistic p.value
##   <dbl> <list>            <list> <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
## 1     1 <tibble [13 x 10~ <lm>   (Intercep~   4.28      3.46      1.24   2.47e-1
## 2     1 <tibble [13 x 10~ <lm>   mpg         -0.101     0.0294   -3.43   7.50e-3
## 3     1 <tibble [13 x 10~ <lm>   qsec         0.0398    0.151     0.264  7.98e-1
## 4     1 <tibble [13 x 10~ <lm>   gear        -0.0229    0.349    -0.0656 9.49e-1
## 5     0 <tibble [19 x 10~ <lm>   (Intercep~   4.92      1.40      3.52   3.09e-3
## 6     0 <tibble [19 x 10~ <lm>   mpg         -0.192     0.0443   -4.33   5.91e-4
## 7     0 <tibble [19 x 10~ <lm>   qsec         0.0919    0.0983    0.935  3.65e-1
## 8     0 <tibble [19 x 10~ <lm>   gear         0.147     0.368     0.398  6.96e-1
What if you want not just the tidy output, but the augment and glance outputs as well, while still performing each regression only once? Since we’re using list-columns, we can just fit the model once and use multiple list-columns to store the tidied, glanced and augmented outputs.

regressions <- mtcars %>%
  nest(-am) %>% 
  mutate(
    fit = map(data, ~ lm(wt ~ mpg + qsec + gear, data = .x)),
    tidied = map(fit, tidy),
    glanced = map(fit, glance),
    augmented = map(fit, augment)
  )

regressions %>% 
  unnest(tidied)
## # A tibble: 8 x 10
##      am data  fit   term  estimate std.error statistic p.value glanced augmented
##   <dbl> <lis> <lis> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <list>  <list>   
## 1     1 <tib~ <lm>  (Int~   4.28      3.46      1.24   2.47e-1 <tibbl~ <tibble ~
## 2     1 <tib~ <lm>  mpg    -0.101     0.0294   -3.43   7.50e-3 <tibbl~ <tibble ~
## 3     1 <tib~ <lm>  qsec    0.0398    0.151     0.264  7.98e-1 <tibbl~ <tibble ~
## 4     1 <tib~ <lm>  gear   -0.0229    0.349    -0.0656 9.49e-1 <tibbl~ <tibble ~
## 5     0 <tib~ <lm>  (Int~   4.92      1.40      3.52   3.09e-3 <tibbl~ <tibble ~
## 6     0 <tib~ <lm>  mpg    -0.192     0.0443   -4.33   5.91e-4 <tibbl~ <tibble ~
## 7     0 <tib~ <lm>  qsec    0.0919    0.0983    0.935  3.65e-1 <tibbl~ <tibble ~
## 8     0 <tib~ <lm>  gear    0.147     0.368     0.398  6.96e-1 <tibbl~ <tibble ~
regressions %>% 
  unnest(glanced)
## # A tibble: 2 x 16
##      am data  fit   tidied r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df
##   <dbl> <lis> <lis> <list>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
## 1     1 <tib~ <lm>  <tibb~     0.833         0.778 0.291     15.0  7.59e-4     4
## 2     0 <tib~ <lm>  <tibb~     0.625         0.550 0.522      8.32 1.70e-3     4
## # ... with 6 more variables: logLik <dbl>, AIC <dbl>, BIC <dbl>,
## #   deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>, augmented <list>
regressions %>% 
  unnest(augmented)
## # A tibble: 32 x 16
##       am data  fit   tidied glanced    wt   mpg  qsec  gear .fitted .se.fit
##    <dbl> <lis> <lis> <list> <list>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
##  1     1 <tib~ <lm>  <tibb~ <tibbl~  2.62  21    16.5     4    2.73   0.209
##  2     1 <tib~ <lm>  <tibb~ <tibbl~  2.88  21    17.0     4    2.75   0.152
##  3     1 <tib~ <lm>  <tibb~ <tibbl~  2.32  22.8  18.6     4    2.63   0.163
##  4     1 <tib~ <lm>  <tibb~ <tibbl~  2.2   32.4  19.5     4    1.70   0.137
##  5     1 <tib~ <lm>  <tibb~ <tibbl~  1.62  30.4  18.5     4    1.86   0.151
##  6     1 <tib~ <lm>  <tibb~ <tibbl~  1.84  33.9  19.9     4    1.56   0.156
##  7     1 <tib~ <lm>  <tibb~ <tibbl~  1.94  27.3  18.9     4    2.19   0.113
##  8     1 <tib~ <lm>  <tibb~ <tibbl~  2.14  26    16.7     5    2.21   0.153
##  9     1 <tib~ <lm>  <tibb~ <tibbl~  1.51  30.4  16.9     5    1.77   0.191
## 10     1 <tib~ <lm>  <tibb~ <tibbl~  3.17  15.8  14.5     5    3.15   0.157
## # ... with 22 more rows, and 5 more variables: .resid <dbl>, .hat <dbl>,
## #   .sigma <dbl>, .cooksd <dbl>, .std.resid <dbl>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to do a step by step of this scenario, wondering why this line doesn't work ` fit<- nested %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(mpg~hp, data=.)))`

Comment: What error do you get? It seems that `nest_by` is not from `dplyr` so I would suggest to try with `nest` as in the example I posted.

Comment: See EDIT on top for your exact case

Comment: Thanks! I cant believe i spent hours on nest vs nest_by

Comment: I ran the exact example Valeri Voev provided (`tidyverse_1.3.0`) and got: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `tidied`.
x Can't convert a `tbl_df/tbl/data.frame` object to function
ℹ Input `tidied` is `map(fit, tidy)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
All elements of `...` must be named.
Did you want `data = c(mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, gear, carb)`?